# How to change users full name on Debian

Tags: debian, user-management

I'm working on a Debian server as an inexperienced admin. I need to change the full name of a user (not the login name) provided during `adduser USERNAME`. How can I do this? I didn't find such an option in `usermod` (http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/usermod8.html).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The [GECOS field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecos_field) in `/etc/password` can be modified with the `chfn(1)` command.

```
chfn -f "Joe Blow" jblow
```

Comment: This also works on RHEL / CentOS.

Comment: Still works on Debian 10 Buster, XFCE, FWIW

Answer (score 14):

You can do the following

`adduser username -c "John Snow" -s /bin/bash`

modify

`usermod -c "Snow John" username`

To verify users' full name  `finger username`

Answer (score 4):

You can edit `/etc/passwd` directly the full name a field in this file.

Comment: although, if you are doing that be sure to use `vipw` instead of simply editing the file the usual way